# Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I just made the move to Visual Studio 2010 from 2008 and I guess I didn't do enough research before I moved.  I seem to have gotten myself in quite a bind.

I knew Crystal Reports was no longer a part of 2010 but the beta was downloadable.  I followed [this document](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/d085f103-ff2d-2d10-2f9e-ffb14d10ef33?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true) for deployment.  My only change to this document is on the bindingRedirect element I changed the newVersion attribute value to 10.5.3700.0 because that is what is in the GAC and what was in the manifest of my 2008 project.

Unfortunately this is not working.  Whenever I try to run a crystal report I get the exception :

An error has occured while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registery key permissions are insufficient or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

At this point I think I am going to have to roll back and go back to VS 2008 until SAP comes out with a runtime.  I can't believe there is not a work around for this as it will break so many projects that have Crystal Reports included in them.

Has anyone been able to work around this?  If so, how?

Comment: it's not got anything to do with running in a 64bit environment, the registry keys are different then..?

Comment: does this help: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/advancedsearch?cat=sdn_ossnotes&query=1200907

Answer (score 0):

Download the required package from here, install it and it will work,
[Crystal Report Runtimes](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp)

Edit:
Original link no longer working. Here is [this other one](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp) (http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp) from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629491/463478)