# SAP Crystal Reports runtime for .Net 4.0 (64-bit)

Tags: .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I need a runtime for SAP Crystal Reports for .Net 4.0 (64-bit). I have been searching from the web but not getting any success. Can I get the URL from where can i download this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

SAP is notoriously bad at making these downloads available... or in an easily accessible location so hopefully this link still works by the time you read this answer.

< original link no longer active >

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824  `Updated Link 2/6/13:`

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads - "Updated 10/31/2017"

http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/ - "Updated 10/31/2017"

Comment: This link already appears to be out of date. I was looking for SAP Crystal Reports for .NET 4.0 (32-bit) and I found this link: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824. It has both 64 and 32 bit links for the Visual Studio 2010 versions.

Comment: Not too shabby, that link stayed active for over a year.  I would call that a recor for SAP.  Thanks for the updated link.

Comment: The above links ends up redirecting the user to the following page https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads.   After reading the article, one needs to provide email address and download the software at http://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/

Comment: https://www.sap.com/products/crystal-visual-studio.html

Comment: This link has all the past and latest downloads 
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Answer (score 8):

I have found a variety of runtimes including Visual Studio(VS) versions are available at
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824