# Error occured while trying to print the crystall report

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4.1, crystal-reports-2008

I'm currently working in the .NET Entity Framework (MySQL 5.0 server) Windows Forms Application. While trying to print the report in client's system, I'm getting the following error message.

Method Errored:GetEffectiveCulture
Error Message:The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception.

Additional Details:   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.GetEffectiveCulture()

at CrystalDecisions.Shared.LocaleManager..ctor()

at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.InitReportViewer()

at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer..ctor()

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)

Comment: i solved the error using following link 
" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374681/the-type-initializer-for-crystaldecisions-shared-sharedutils-threw-an-exceptio "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the connection string path to the database is correct or not. If any `dataset` is formed then configure it and check its connections.

Comment: thanks for your answer, while trying to launch the application in clients system all other parts of referring database is working except trying to print the crystal reports.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem using following link

http://www.logicaltrinkets.com/wordpress/?p=213