# 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, unhandled-exception

I'm working on a project. the databsae is in the server not in my local. When I run my code I get the error message: "CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils" threw an exception.I receive this error at this line of code:

```
this.crystalReportViewer1 = 
      new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();
```

I wrote some code in app.config file. I tried diffrent ways but I didn't fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without the exact exception type/message, not much help can be given.

Comment: You should look to see if the exception being thrown has an inner exception. If it does, [this Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12374681/656243) may be relevant.