# Customer PC cannot run report without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, crystal-reports

My C# application uses many reports. They run correctly on my PC as it has Crystal Reports for Visual Studio installed. However when I move to my Client's PC without Visual studio (but with Crystal Report Runtime Client Version) it throws this exception:

> Type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils' threw an exception

What is the cause of this problem and how can I solve it for my client?

Comment: that error isn't useful. Try displaying the error message to see exactly what is going wrong

Comment: did you see any clue from here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374681/the-type-initializer-for-crystaldecisions-shared-sharedutils-threw-an-exceptio