# Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web version=10.5.3700.0' in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, web-config, crystal-reports-2008

I have a problem when I use Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2008. In my local server it's no problem, but when I put this in my production server, it shows me this error:

```
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.OutlookViewCtl, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
        <add assembly="Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
```

Comment: Looks like the production server is unable to find the assembies, can you check the bin folder?

Comment: yes there is no assemblies files what can i do?@RaviShankar

Comment: This happens  because of missing crystal report runtime component in server check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591923/sap-crystal-reports-runtime-for-net-4-0-64-bit

Comment: now am getting one error CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None; @RaviShankar

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the required DLLs to the production server.  You can install in the GAC or simply in the web \bin folder.

Alternatively, install the Crystal 10.5 runtime on the server so the files are properly registered in the GAC.

Comment: yes i done that issue after that am getting one error The 'DisplayGroupTree' property cannot be set declaratively. @Doug Knudsen

Comment: <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrvDisplay" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" DisplayGroupTree="False"
        ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false" EnableParameterPrompt="false" />