# Cystal report version 7 installation failure "Setup system error"

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm getting the following error message when installing and configuring the Seagate Crystal Reports Setup. I'm trying to install the crystal report version 7 and it says it requires Java 7.05 along with the installation of the crystal reports.
I'm trying to install the same on windows 7 ultimate operating system with 64 bit with SP1 of the system type x64-based laptop.

Comment: Install the required Java or higher.  Install Crystal Report runtime.  Then try install Seagate CR.

Comment: Sir, The version of java is as mentioned here. java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode). Could you please provide the links for installation of crystal report runtime and Seagate CR. Thank you for your kind reply.

Comment: Cr Runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591923/sap-crystal-reports-runtime-for-net-4-0-64-bit

Seagate CR - if you are going through the setup, you must have the install link already.