# Does visual studio 2010 supports crystal reports version 10.5.3700.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

previously I have used Visual studio 2008.Now I **migrated to VS2010**.I have a problem with Crystal reports. Previously those are in Version=**10.5.3700.0** .**How can i get crystal reports in  same version for VS2010**.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts, Rakesh.

Comment: What is the problem? Is it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2923627/560648)? Did you read the release notes for "Crystal Reports"? What does the vendor say?

Comment: Sorry  Lightness Races in Orbit  .I didn't read the Release Notes for "Crystal Reports" .Can you please suggest me whether it supports or not.? If does not support   I need to convert my entire project for this.

Comment: Please go ahead and read the Release Notes now. That's better than me looking them up and doing it for you. Also follow the link that I lovingly provided for you.